# Sign Convention in Ray Optics

Tags: optics, conventions, refraction, geometric-optics

While solving questions on Refraction due to 2 spherical surfaces the sign of the image formed after the first refraction (here at '$A$') depends whether the image formed is towards left or right side of the 2nd surface as our pole will change after the first refraction

Here Pole changes to $B$ from $A$ after the first refraction. Let the image formed after the first refraction is at x coordinate (x>0) with respect to $A$ such that x lies towards the right of the surface $B$.

Then we have coordinate of the image as x-2R (R is the radius)with respect to $B$.
[image]

If the image formed after the first refraction was towards left of the surface $B$ then again we have coordinate of image with respect to $B$ is x-2R.
[image]

But had the image been towards the left of  surface $A$ then coordinate of image with respect to $B$ is -x-2R.
[image]

So whenever values will not be given then we have to take cases, but it will really make the question very very lengthy.

The original question due to which I had this doubt
[image]

I solved this question by using geometry. But if numeric values were given then I would have easily solved it by using the above method too.

So my question is how to determine sign convention in case of questions where variables are given instead of numbers.

Please help.

EDIT - I added the 3rd case and made some changes in the 2nd case.

Comment: In the second case, the coordinate of the image with respect to B is still x-2R. You move 2R to the left and x to the right from B. The sign of the image distance changes, but the expression doesn't.

Comment: More on [sign conventions in optics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+sign*+convention*+optics).

Comment: @Sankalp Thankyou. I made the changes but it will be -x-2R in 3rd case right?

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks.

Comment: @Mathematics If you are taking 'x' to be the coordinate of image with respect to A, it would still be x-2R, as x itself is a -ve value. For example, if x = -25cm, and R = 50cm, the coordinate with respect to B would be -125cm = -25cm - 2*50cm = x-2R.

Comment: @Sankalp I'd already defined x>0, I thought about it like you told (like modulus function in maths) but it did not work in the question I posted below. I will post my attempt as well

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, if you are using the simple lens or mirror formula, the distance from a real object or image to the refracting surface is assumed to be positive. With a virtual object or image, the distance is negative. With a virtual object, the rays striking the surface are converging and the distance is from the surface to where they would converge without the surface.  With a virtual image, the rays leaving the surface are diverging, and the distance is to their apparent source.